# Unable to use vera++ on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation

I wanted to use vera++. Based on the references, I executed

```
sudo apt-get install vera++
```

on my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 32-bit system.

But when I checked later, it showed that the package has not been installed.

I got this when I executed the above command:

[image]

When I checked for the version,

[image]

When I executed,

```
    apt-cache policy vera\+\+
```

I got

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you find/enable a PPA for this? According to packages.ubuntu.com `vera++` was only added to the official (universe) repo from 14.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, according to [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=vera%2B%2B&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) the `vera++` package has been added to official repository since Ubuntu 14.04.

In other words, you can't install the packaged version.

You have basically two options:

1. Find a PPA for your version of Ubuntu like [this one](https://launchpad.net/~smspillaz/+archive/ubuntu/verapp-latest) and add it to your system:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:smspillaz/verapp-latest
   ```

   Afterwards you would just update cache:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```

   And simply install the packaged version:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install vera\+\+
   ```
2. Compile this software from source code, which I won't post. I am just mentioning it for the sake of coherency of the answer.